# Effect of Any() on the state of an IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

suppose i have a code already working that goes like this

```
....
....

foreach(object item in enumerator.GetItems(arg1, arg2....)
{

}

....
....
```

where `getItems` is a method of an abstract class (`abstractEnumerator`), and `getItems` returns an `IEnumerable<object>`.

The problem arises because now i would like to use the Any() LINQ extension before the foreach to check if the enumerable is empty, and i want to be sure that it wont change at all the 'state' of the IEnumerable when it reaches the foreach, in order to make sure that the code behaves exactly as before.

However, the tricky part, is i do not have access to the implementations of abstractEnumerator, and therefore, i do not have access to the underlying implementation of the IEnumerable interface.

For all i know the Reset method of the interface could be returning null without doing anything. Imagine that the implementations of the abstractEnumerator are created by third party developers from another company, so i do not have access to their code.

My question is if i can be sure that the state will remain the same, when adding the Any() before the for each, regardless of the underlying implementation.

According to microsoft reference on Any:

*' The enumeration of source is stopped as soon as the result can be determined. '*

In this case, that i want to stop on the first element (basically what i want to ask is whether the IEnumerable is empty or not), does this means that the enumeration stops ***before*** processing the first element (i.e. the state is the same as if Any() wasnt called, regardless of the implementation), or it stops ***after*** processing the first element?

Answer (score 6):

Often enumerables themselves are effectively stateless - the state comes in the *enumerator* which is returned by `GetEnumerator()`. However, if you want to avoid calling `GetEnumerator()` twice (which could easily give different results each time, of course), the simplest thing is just to remember whether or not you saw any elements:

```
bool any = false;
foreach (var element in GetItems(...))
{
    any = true;
}
if (any)
{
    // whatever
}
```

That won't help if you want to take an action *before* the first iteration, of course. If you want to do that, you could use the iterator yourself:

```
using (var iterator = GetItems(...).GetEnumerator())
{
    if (iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        // Take your "pre-iteration" action
    }
    do
    {
        var item = iterator.Current;
        // Use the item
    } while (iterator.MoveNext());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, and for the suggestions. Ive thought of them (or similar solutions), the problem is i dont think they are as clean as the original implementation of the foreach. I understand that there is no other way though. Just a question, if the Reset method is correctly implemented, then when i call the Any method using the LINQ the iterator gets wrapped in an using statement and therefore when i call it from the for each the enumerator is resetted right? In which case would the enumerator return different results? Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @user282724: Unfortunately it's hard to suggest other things when we don't know what you're trying to do with the information... do you need to take action first? Afterwards? How many items do you expect? (You could always copy them into a `List<T>` first, at which point you can call `Any` or `Count` or whatever as much as you like on the list...)

Comment: @user282724: As for your question about `Reset` - no, that's completely irrelevant... it's not that the enumerator is *reset* between calling `Any` and the `foreach` loop... there will be two entirely separate iterators. Both `Any` and the `foreach` loop will call `GetEnumerator()`, and each call to `GetEnumerator()` should return an independent iterator. As for something that returns different results each time - `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => GenerateSomeRandomNumber())` for example...